# Mercurial Queues: How to reorder patches efficiently

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

Suppose I have the follow patches in my mercurial queue:

```
$ hg qser -v
 0 A p1
 1 A p2
 2 A p3-StupidPatch
 3 A p4
 5 A p6
 ...
15 A p15
```

Now suppose that I want to do is reorder the patches so that p3-Stupid patch is the last patch.  IE:

```
$ hg qser -v
 0 A p1
 1 A p2
 2 A p4
 3 A p6
 ...
14 A p15
15 A p3-StupidPatch
```

I know that I could do it like this:

```
$ # Pop patches until p2
$ hg qpop p2
$
$ hg qser -v
 0 A p1
 1 A p2
 2 U p3-StupidPatch
 3 U p4
 5 U p6
 ...
15 U p15
$
$ # Push patches one by one
$ hg qpush --move  p4
$ hg qpush --move p5
$ hg qpush --move p6
$ hg qpush --move p7
$ hg qpush --move p8
$ hg qpush --move p9
$ hg qpush --move p10
$ hg qpush --move p11
$ hg qpush --move p12
$ hg qpush --move p13
$ hg qpush --move p14
$ hg qpush --move p15
$ hg qpush --move p3-StupidPatch
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You might consider switching to `hg ci --secret`, `hg rebase`, and `hg histedit` instead of MQ.  The core developers [don't like MQ](http://gregoryszorc.com/blog/2014/06/23/please-stop-using-mq/) and are at least *thinking* about [deprecating it](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqDeprecationPlan).

Comment: I fully agree. However, I'd make an additional suggestion to use 'Mercurial evolution', as it means you'll be able to use these commands without any risk (the old un-rebased changesets will still exist, just hidden).

Comment: Sadly, `hg evolve` is not stable enough for me to recommend it for production use.  I'd wait until it gets moved into core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hgtk log` to reorder patches like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could unapply all the patches and change the order in the file  `.hg/patches/series`. That's where the order is really stored.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way. Make sure you pay close attention when applying them the first time after rearranging in case some hunks fail.